# Moving files with powershell by filename numbering

Tags: powershell

I'm a total noob with powershell but after reading a little I came up with the following code. As you can see I'm using "Write-Output" for testing my code but the final use for it will be moving files to new folders. The files that will be brought to folders are the ones the break the pattern "+2 sequence" so if the files names are "x_x_0002,x_x_0004,x_x_0006,x_x_0008,x_x_0012,x_x_0016,x_x_0018,x_x_0020 ..." the selected files will be "x_x_0008,x_x_0012,x_x_0018" and those will move to a folder named by number of the last file in the group, "18 in this example (probably I should think for a sequential folder naming but I can solve after this). I'm close but this code fails on the last two items from the group, my approach skips the second to last one. I hope someone could lend me a hand. Thanks, and pardon my english :$

```
$Source = "G:\output\test"
$oldNum = 0
$sfiles = @()
Get-ChildItem $Source | ForEach-Object{
    $cropTxt = $_.Basename.Split("_")[2]
    $currNum = [convert]::ToInt32($cropTxt, 10)
    $diff = $currNum - $oldNum
    If ($diff -eq $currNum) {
        $oldNum = $currNum
    }
    else{
        if ($diff -eq 2) {
            if($sfiles.Count -ne 0){
                $sfiles += $currNum
                $sfiles += "----"
                $sfiles | ForEach-Object {
                    Write-Output $_
                }
                $sfiles = @()
            }
        }
        else{
            $sfiles += $oldNum
        }
        $oldNum = $currNum
    }
}
```

Comment: A new day and new ideas, here is the code that finally worked out

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
$Source = "G:\output\test"
$oldNum = 0
$currFolder = 18
$sfiles = @()
Get-ChildItem $Source | ForEach-Object{
    $cropTxt = $_.Basename.Split("_")[2]
    $currNum = [convert]::ToInt32($cropTxt, 10)
    $currFile = $_.Fullname
    $diff = $currNum - $oldNum
    If ($diff -eq $currNum) {
        $oldNum = $currNum
        $oldFile = $currFile
    }
    else{
        if ($diff -eq 2) {
            if($sfiles.Count -ne 0){
                #$sfiles += $oldNum
                #$sfiles += "----"
                $sfiles += $oldFile
                New-Item -Path "$Source\$currFolder" -ItemType Directory
                $sfiles | ForEach-Object {
                    move-item -Path $_ -Destination "$Source\$currFolder"
                }
                $currFolder = $currFolder + 1
                $sfiles = @()
            }
        }
        else{
            $sfiles += $oldFile
        }
        $oldNum = $currNum
        $oldFile = $currFile
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).